# Getting manager of manager of an employee using django-auth-ldap

Tags: django, python-3.x, active-directory, django-ldapdb

i need some help if someone run into the same problem i am having right now, as i have been asked to add support a login using Active Directory, i have managed to succeed the login process and the models creations of users, and now i want to populate some details from AD into the app database, i want to get the manager of manager of an employee, as i have been searching i found that the team lead N+1 field is named "manager" on ad so i have queried this using this command

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "Name",
    "email": "mail",
    "employee_manager": "manager",
    "employee_office": "physicalDeliveryOfficeName",
    "employee_cost_center": "extensionAttribute8" 
}
```

The problem here is i got this in my database

```
CN=TeamLeadName,OU=Users,OU=T,OU=C,OU=C,DC=domain,DC=net
```

so know i don't have any idea how to get only the name of the team lead and not the rest and from there how i can get the team of the team lead or in other word the initial employee manager. 
Any help will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`manager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-manager) attribute gives you the [`distinguishedName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada1/56da5a9b-485d-4d7c-a226-1a54a43d9013) of the manager's account. You can use that to look up the manager's account and get the name (you'd probably want the `displayName`).

The django-auth-ldap package has [python-ldap](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.2.0/) as a dependency, so you can use that to look up the account. I'm not a python developer, so I'm sure this needs work, but putting together [the documentation](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.2.0/reference/ldap.html#example) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729539/how-do-i-search-for-an-object-in-ldap-based-on-its-dn-in-python-ldap), it should look something like this:

```py
import ldap

...

l = ldap.initialize('ldap://example.com')
r = l.search_s(manager, ldap.SCOPE_BASE, '(objectClass=*)', ['displayName'])
```

Where `manager` is the `distinguishedName` of the manager that you just found, and "example.com" is your domain name.

Comment: I have tried this, when i print r i get this [('CN=Lead Name ,OU=Users,OU=Tunis,OU=Care,OU=Corporate,DC=domain,DC=net', {'displayName': [b'Lead Name']})]

Comment: So you can pull the `displayName` from that with `r[0][1]['displayName'][0]`

Comment: yess i have found also the attribute for the team lead of the manager and i can query it as well, thank for your help